# How to iterate over points to split linestring into portions in PgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, geometry, postgis

**Context** : I'm working with a PostgreSQL (10.6) database and PostGIS 2.5.

I need help creating a function that'll split the linestring of each row from a table using points from another table, and insert the split portions into a new table. Each line has it's proper points and the points have a precise order.

I know how to split a linestring using `ST_Line_Substring` ([documentation here](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html)), and I know how to do it using a point using `ST_LineLocatePoint` ([documentation here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html)).

---

I have 2 problems : I don't want to split the line at a point's location, but rather in between each point according to their position on the line as fraction. So if there is a point at 0% and the next one is at 20% of the line, the first portion would go from 0% to 10% of the original line. Here's a quick illustration (sorry if it looks childish) : [image]

The black line represent the original linestring, the blue circles are the points, and the colored "lines" represent what kind of line_substring I want.

The solution I came up with this problem is just just adding the fraction of the previous point and current point on the line and dividing by 2 for the start of the portion, and same thing with the current point and the next one, for the end of the portion, as written below :

```
ST_Line_Substring(line.geom, (
    ((ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom, previous_point.geom) + ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom, current_point.geom)) / 2),
    ((ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom, current_point.geom) + ST_LineLocatePoint(line.geom, next_point.geom)) / 2)
)
```

My 2nd problem, I have no idea how to access the previous and next point from the table containing the points. At first I wanted to use some kind of loop mechanism but I've seen a lot of answers from other topics saying this isn't something optimal and it's better to avoid them, and I've found nothing looking like an index in SQL to iterate over a result set or a table to easily access previous or next element.

So my main question is, how do I iterate over my points table, for each line, to access previous, current, and next point at the same time ?

Comment: Hey Adrien. Could you also provide a few raw data? Maybe subqueries or a CTE should do. Terrific illustration btw.

Comment: @JimJones I'm not very used to CTE, what kind of raw data would you like ? Just a few rows to see how the tables are made ?

Comment: A create table statement and a few records would help others to reproduce your environment and will significantly improve your chances to get an answer:-) A CTE is nothing more than a mechanism to create a temporary table based on a query, so that you're able to query it in a second statement. Quite powerful, but can become very slow when dealing with large tables.

Comment: Here's table creations and some tuple to insert : http://collabedit.com/vk78w
I didn't add the geometry data because I can't share it, you just need to know it's stored in SRID 4326 format. The points are somewhat regularly positionned close to the line, but they're not on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I'm using a cursor and then the RELATIVE option, which allows me to access other indexes than the row I'm iterating over, here's what my function looks like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitLine(
    id character varying,
    linestring geometry(POINT,4326)
    )
RETURNS VOID AS $$

DECLARE
prior_point RECORD;
current_point RECORD;
next_point RECORD;
cursor_point SCROLL CURSOR FOR  SELECT id, line_id, line_order, geom
                                  FROM points
                                  WHERE id LIKE line_id
                                  ORDER BY line_order;

BEGIN

    OPEN cursor_points;

    LOOP

        FETCH FROM cursor_point INTO prior_point;
        FETCH RELATIVE 1 FROM cursor_point INTO current_point;
        FETCH RELATIVE 2 FROM cursor_point INTO next_point;

        -- Operations on my points and line 

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_point;
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```